# require-js: shim doesn't seem to work properly, fails with "jQuery is not defined"

Tags: magento2, requirejs

Im trying to integrate the popular `stellar.js`-module into my theme.

I go with the following. In my `requirejs-config.js` I have:

```
var config = {
    map: {
            '*': {
                'stellar': 'js/jquery.stellar.min'
            }
        },
        "shim": {
                "stellar": ["jquery"]
            }
};
```

and I utilize it by doing it this way:

```
require(['jquery', 'stellar'], function($) {
```

However, in my console I get this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.stellar.min.js:2
```

Whats wrong here? The stellar plugin hasn't got modified from me.

Comment: please show your js file absolute path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **requirejs-config.js** file code like below :

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "stellar": "Vendor_Modulename/js/jquery.stellar.min"
        }
    }
};
```

Make sure your **js file location** is **view/frontend/web/js/jquery.stellar.min.js**

and at last load your jquery in the **template file(.phtml) like below code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery', 'stellar'],function($){
        (function() {

        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's a theme, so technically its just "js/...", which is it already.

Comment: @Max if it is theme then pass "Vendor_Themename
"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'stellar' is dependant on jQuery, try changing to this:

```
var config = {
  paths:{
    'jquery.stellar':'js/jquery.stellar.min'
  },
  shim:{
    'jquery.stellar':{
        'deps':['jquery']
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: No change here, :/